# Windows Embedded Standard 7 WEDU updates do not install

Tags: windows-embedded, windows-embedded-standard

I use WEDU to search for updates and to download and install them to my WES7 SP1 Distribution Share.
I have done that many times before and it usually works fine.
I want to make a configuration set of updates and security updates, that I can apply to an existing image.

Now I tried using WEDU again
WEDU finds 4 updates that it needs to download and install.
[WEDU shows 4 updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIYfI.png)
I “Select all” and click “Download and Install”
After the install has completed, I get a dialog box that tells me that 4 items were successfully installed. So far so good.
I then start up ICE and look for the 4 updates. 
I can’t find them.

I then start WEDU again and press “Start Scan”
The result is that it finds the exact same 4 updates for download. And so it goes around and around in circles.

I have had a look in the folder structure of my distribution share and I cannot find the updates.

Why aren't the updates being installed to my Distribution share and what can I do to fix it?
Thanks in advance

(WEDU has version 2.0.0695.0)

Comment: nice, if you solved it go ahead and add an Answer with some of the the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Richard Eaton of Avnet Embedded UK, I got the solution: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3138095/wedu-re-offers-updates-that-were-already-downloaded-in-windows-embedded-7